# add smart checklist to jira task from api

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a jira user story from powershell using the rest api.
I want to add a smart checklist to the task when its created.

ill send following json to the endpoint

```
{
"fields":
{
"project":
    {
    "key": "dep"
    },
"issuetype": 
    {
    "name": "Story"
    },
"summary": "Order: 5, Tasktype: New_table",
"description": "Auto created Jira task for a data task\n ",
"assignee":
    {
    "key": "da",
    "name": "da",
    "emailAddress": "da@mycompany.com"
    },

"labels": ["DATA"],
"customfield_10001": "DWH-62",
"customfield_10006": 0
"--data": /****************************here i try to add a checklist 
{
 "- ToDo \n+ Checked\nx Skipped\n~ In Progress\n" 
},

}'
```

But i won't work

Error reponse is

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At S:\XXX\XXX1\SIJ\scripts\jira-test.ps1:49 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri $restapiuri  -Headers $headers  -Method POST - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke- 
RestMethod], WebException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In spite of the fact that the Atlassian documentation indicates that you can create a Smart Checklist when you create an issue, I could not get it to work. What I ended up doing was creating the issue first, then making a call to add the Checklist using the checklist API, something like this:

```
await Client.RestClient.ExecuteRequestAsync(RestSharp.Method.PUT, $"{JiraUri}/rest/api/2/issue/{issue}/properties/com.railsware.SmartChecklist.checklist", "\"- Item 1\\n- Item 2\\n- Item 3\\n\"");
```

I found the documentation here: https://railsware.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CHK/pages/92176610/Jira+REST+API.+Read+Write+checklists

and it worked for me.